# Automatically Copy numeric values from different column which has numeric cells & alphabetic cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column (Suppose Column B) in which some numeric data cell & also some cells which contains alphabets only, and I want to copy only numeric data in a different column (Suppose Column C).

to do that currently I am first filtering the column with numeric values only & then coping the same in different column.

some of my data of Column B are:-

-6,438464696
Not Failed
Not Failed
Not Failed
-6,197908195
-6,004067583
-5,841704298
Not Failed
Not Failed
Not Failed

and i want to copy the same in another column C which contains only:-

-6,438464696
-6,197908195
-6,004067583
-5,841704298

so if there a formula by which, the Column C will change automatically if there is change in column B.

Regards,
Jai

Answer (score 0):

try his one:
Your data in col B, the equation in the cell in col C

C1=IF(T(B1)="",B1,NA())

you will then have the 'no value' indicator in cell c1 .

The if() command tests if in B1 is text (T(B1), and execute then the steps after, i.e. copy the value or indicating #N/A.

You can, after the second comma in the if brackets put any value you want.

T.